# How to use MFCC feature extraction method while fine-tuning the Wav2Vec2 pretrained model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, huggingface-transformers, mfcc, huggingface-datasets

I am going through some blogs on fine-tuning the Wav2Vec2 pretrained model on my custom dataset. Below are the resources for the same. 
https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/multi_lingual_speech_recognition.ipynb#scrollTo=GNFuvi26Yiw6 
https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-xlsr-wav2vec2 
I am able to complete the entire process and results are also generated as expected. Below is an excerpt of a section where they have mentioned that we can use other feature extraction method like MFCC's.

> Finally, we can leverage Wav2Vec2Processor to process the data to the
> format expected by the model for training. To do so let's make use of
> Dataset's map(...) function. First, we load and resample the audio
> data, simply by calling batch["audio"]. Second, we extract the
> input_values from the loaded audio file. In our case, the
> Wav2Vec2Processor only normalizes the data. For other speech models,
> however, this step can include more complex feature extraction, such
> as Log-Mel feature extraction. Third, we encode the transcriptions to
> label ids.

This is the part where I am stuck since days. I have tried all the ways but still not able to proceed. I was able to change the `input_values` generated by the Wav2Vec2 Processor to MFCC's values as represented in below code but still no luck.

```
def prepare_dataset(batch):
    audio = batch["audio"]

    batch["input_values"] = processor(audio["array"], sampling_rate=audio["sampling_rate"]).input_values[0]
    batch["input_length"] = len(batch["input_values"])
    
    with processor.as_target_processor():
        batch["labels"] = processor(batch["sentence"]).input_ids
    return batch
```

By changing the Wav2Vec2Processor `input_values` which was a 1D float array to MFCC's coefficients 1D float array, I was able to train the model but while the evaluation step, it throwed me this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-3435b262f1ae> in <module>()
----> 1 trainer.train()

<ipython-input-143-57d9e4596fb5> in <listcomp>(.0)
     17         # split inputs and labels since they have to be of different lenghts and need
     18         # different padding methods
---> 19         input_features = [{"input_values": feature["input_values"]} for feature in features]
     20         label_features = [{"input_ids": feature["labels"]} for feature in features]
     21 

KeyError: 'input_values'
```

How should I proceed with using the MFCC feature extraction with the Wav2Vec2 pretrained model?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problems with my custom dataset. You could try the prepare_dataset() function from this [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/kingabzpro/fine-tuning-xlsr-wav2vec2-for-wolof-asr-with/notebook), section [33].